# Kafka: Auto flush data for every 1GB

Tags: apache-kafka

Which property I have to set for auto delete or auto-flush out data of a topic in Kafka broker.

I tried to edit the following properties but it didn't make any difference.

```
log.retention.ms
log.retention.byte
log.retention.check.interval.ms
```

But still whenever 1 GB is reaching it is not deleting the flush
So, uncommented below properties along with above

```
log.flush.interval.messages
log.flush.interval.ms
```

How much ever I may increase values of these properties it is deleting data around 180 MB Maximum.

How to delete data automatically whenever data for particular topic reaches 1GB.

Answer (score 1):

**log.retention.ms** and **log.retention.bytes** are the properties of a broker which is used as a default value when a topic is created. When you change configurations of currently running topic using kafka-topics.sh, you should specify a topic-level property.

A topic-level property for log retention time are **retention.ms** and **retention.bytes**.

Try below command to set retention by time:

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --topic as-access --config retention.ms=86400000

Try below command to set retention by size:

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --alter --topic as-access --config retention.bytes=1048576

Command to verify if properties are set to topic:

> bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper zk.yoursite.com --topic as-access

Then you will see something like below.

> Topic:as-access  PartitionCount:3  ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:retention.ms=86400000

Comment: This is working perfectly fine, as per my use case, data should be flushed as soon as it reaches 1GB, so retention.ms should be set to as minimum as possible. Along with that log.retention.check.interval.ms, this property to be set

Comment: log.retention.check.interval.ms - The frequency in milliseconds that the log cleaner checks whether any log is eligible for deletion.
That's right!